# Copy one xml and generate another with modified values

Tags: apex, xml, xmlparsing

I need to copy one xml and need to generate another xml file. The purpose of creating another xml file is to have modified data. I'm using below code

```
 public static void parseXMl(String strResp){
    system.debug('Akshat XML COntent ' + strResp);
    Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();  
    DOM.Document docToGenerate = new DOM.Document();
    doc.load(strResp);  
    Dom.XMLNode rootElement = doc.getRootElement();  
    docToGenerate.createRootElement(rootElement.getName(), null, null);
    for ( Dom.XMLNode childElement : rootElement.getChildElements() ) {
        //root elements of each array
       
        docToGenerate.addChildElement(childElement.getName(), null, null);   
        for (Dom.XMLNode detailElement : childElement.getChildElements()){
            //childs elements of each array
            docToGenerate.addChildElement(childElement.getName(), null, null).addTextNode(detailElement.getText()); 
           
            for (Dom.XMLNode detailElement1 : detailElement.getChildElements()){
                
            docToGenerate.addChildElement(detailElement.getName(), null, null).addTextNode(detailElement1.getText()); 
               
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

In **docToGenerate** I want new xml file. This code is wrong as its throwing me error for addChildElement and other methods I used on docToGenerate variable.
I'm new to this, I'm able to parse existing xml but not sure how I can create new xml

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Voila!
I achieved this requirement with below code

```
public static void parseXMl(String strResp){
    String rootElementToGenerate = '';
    Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();  
    DOM.Document docToGenerate = new DOM.Document();
    doc.load(strResp);  
    Dom.XMLNode rootElement = doc.getRootElement(); 
    rootElementToGenerate =  rootElement.getName();
    dom.XmlNode rootNodeElementToGenerate = docToGenerate.createRootElement(rootElement.getName(), null, null);
    for ( Dom.XMLNode childElement : rootElement.getChildElements() ) {
        String childElementToGenerate = childElement.getName();
        dom.XMLNode childNodeElementToGenerate = rootNodeElementToGenerate.addChildElement(childElementToGenerate, null, null);   
        for (Dom.XMLNode detailElement : childElement.getChildElements()){
            
            String childElementToGenerate1 = detailElement.getName();
            //childs elements of each array
            dom.XMLNode childNodeElementToGenerate1 = childNodeElementToGenerate.addChildElement(childElementToGenerate1, null, null).addTextNode(detailElement.getText()); 
            for (Dom.XMLNode detailElement1 : detailElement.getChildElements()){
            String childElementToGenerate2 = detailElement1.getName();
            dom.XMLNode childNodeElementToGenerate2 = childNodeElementToGenerate1.addChildElement(childElementToGenerate2, null, null).addTextNode(detailElement1.getText()); 
            //docToGenerate.addChildElement(detailElement.getName(), null, null).addTextNode(detailElement1.getText()); 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

and **docToGenerate.toXmlString()** will give you newly generated xml.

Posting answer here in case if its helpful for anyone!